# Calculating the volume of rotation between $y=4x-16$, $x^2-y^2=9$ around $x$ axis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Having the following equations:
$y=4x-16$, 
$x^2-y^2=9$

I calculated the mutual points - $(53/15,-28/15),(5,4)$
How can I find the volume of rotation of the area in between them around the $x$ axis? Should it be split into two different volumes?

I've tried calculating the volume above axis x and the volume below it separately. 
Above axis x I'm getting $2\pi$ :
$$V_1 = \pi\cdot \int^5_4(4x-16)^2dx - \pi \int^4_3(\sqrt{x^2-9})^2dx = 2\pi$$

and below I got $1.446\pi$:

$$V_2 =\pi\cdot \int ^4_{53/15}(4x-16)^2dx + \pi\int^{53/15}_{3}(\sqrt{x^2-9}^2dx = 1.446\pi$$

So In total I get a final result of $V= V_1+V_2 = 3.446\pi$. Is there anything I did wrong in my calculation?

Comment: What is the axis of rotation?

Comment: The axis of the rotation is $x$. Thanks

Comment: Calculate one volume, subtract it from other. Which parts don't you understand or are having trouble?

Comment: Also the circle can be replaced with a sphere, $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and the line with double cone to solve in Cartesian. Or use polar coordinates to use the $\theta$ limit of integration to revolve around. Or even use the geometry and formulas for volumes for different shapes maybe. Try drawing it to get an idea of what's going on too.

Comment: The curves don't intersect.

Comment: I Accidently put + instead of -. Fixed it now, thanks again

Comment: Eh your probably gonna have to change those over to polar coordinates and revolve around the axis.

Comment: Could you take a look at what I did? Does this look valid and correct?

Comment: Sorry I made mistake thinking was circle not hyperboloid didnt notice $-$ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume can indeed be found by splitting it into different sub-volumes. The first volume is obtained by rotating the hyperbola around the $x$ axis from $x=3$ (the apex of the hyperbola) to $x=4$ (the point at which the line crosses the $x$ axis.  The second volume can be found from the difference between the two rotated curves -- onwards from $x=4$ to $x=5$ (the second intersection point).

I.e. we can write it as

$\qquad \pi \int_3^4 x^2-9 \, dx + \pi \int_4^5 
x^2-9 \,dx - \pi \int_4^5 (4x - 16)^2 \, dx
$

which simplifies to

$\qquad \pi \int_3^5 x^2-9 \, dx
- \pi \int_4^5 (4x - 16)^2 \, dx
$

I make the result $28\pi/3$. In the integral between $x=3$ and $x=4$, the rotated hyperbola will `fill the gap' below the line $y=4x-16$.

I have interpreted the region between the curves as extending all the way from the apex of the hyperbola, so that the first integral starts at 3 (rather than 53/15). If you want to start at the intersection, then the first limit in the first integral can be changed.

[image: The curve and the line showing the regions of integration]

In the image, the red/green show the positive/negative halves of the hyperbola, the vertical line shows the split between areas that are rotated to form the volume.

Comment: But don't we need to calculate also the volume of the part below the $x$ axis? From $x=3$ to $x=4$. From what I see you only related to the area above it. Am I missing something?

Comment: When the positive part of the hyperbola (between 3 and 4) is rotated fully about the $x$ axis, the volume that it creates will fully contain the volume that would be generated by rotating the part of the region that is below the axis. If we included that we would be counting a part of the required volume twice.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, can you tell me which software you used to draw the graphs?

Comment: No problem. I used Python to create the graph, there is a printout of a Jupyter notebook [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzz9ICVGwwhHaVdaTGlxUGJJdGs).

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the calculation via the method of cylindrical shells or with washers.

First, a sketch of the region in question:

[image]

This shows that you have an issue if this region is to be rotated about the $x$-axis, since the relevant cross-section is the portion enclosed by the two curves **above** the $x$-axis (else you will double-count the volume from the portion of the region below the $x$-axis when you revolve it).  Hence, by the method of cylindrical shells, the radius of the shell ranges from $y = 0$ to $y = 4$, and the height of the shell is given by $$h(y) = (y+16)/4 - \sqrt{y^2+9}.$$  Thus a representative shell has differential volume $$dV = 2 \pi y h(y) \, dy = 2 \pi y \left(\frac{y}{4} + 4 - \sqrt{y^2+9}\right) \, dy,$$ and the total volume is $$V = 2\pi \int_{y=0}^4 \frac{y^2}{4} + 4y - y\sqrt{y^2+9} \, dy = 2\pi \left[\frac{y^3}{12} + 2y^2 - \frac{(y^2+9)^{3/2}}{3}\right]_{y=0}^4 = \frac{28}{3}\pi.$$

If we perform the calculation using washers, we have from $x = 3$ to $x = 4$ the volume $$V_1 = \int_{x=3}^4 \pi( x^2-9) \, dx = \pi \left[\frac{x^3}{3} - 9x\right]_{x=3}^4 = \frac{10}{3}\pi,$$ and from $x = 4$ to $x = 5$, $$V_2 = \int_{x=4}^5 \pi \left(x^2 - 9 - (4x-16)^2\right) \, dx = \pi \left[-5x^3 + 64x^2 - 265x\right]_{x=4}^5 = 6 \pi.$$
From this, the total volume is again $$\frac{28}{3}\pi.$$

Comment: Could you further explain why only must the section above the x axis should be taken into consideration? I didn't get that part

Comment: @S.Peter I already explained this in my answer.  If you rotate a region about a line that intersects it, the resulting volume of revolution will overlap itself.  If you take a circle and rotate it about a diameter, after you've rotated it $\pi$ radians, you've completed a sphere.  If you continue rotating, however, you would start to overlap:  no additional volume is created.  You could fix this by instead rotating a semicircle through $2\pi$ radians.  The same idea applies here.